# Height restriction?

Tags: height

Please help with these two issues, I will happily pay$ to get these two obstacles out of my way. I got this template from envato and my skills are very slow progressing.

http://philpadilla.com/demo/project.html

Fashion Models
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                           Mobile · Web

How do I edit the css to expand the image heights to 100%? My graphics will be stacked just like the template but they will vary in height and I need them to not have the tops and bottoms of the images clipped off. I have been digging and cant seem to find the solution. I also want to turn the rollovers off on all the project images. Does anyone have it in their heart to help please?

Answer (score 1):

The images on your template are already with a predefined value, to change that, you can:

- Edit the inline style of your image
- Create a external stylesheet to change the height

[image: The code]

You can try setting height to 100% (`height:100%;`)

The easiest way to turn the rollover of, is creating a new stylesheet (style.css) and including it on your code (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`)

`thumb-overlay { display: none; } /* This code will disable the rollovers */ }`

`img { height: 100%; } /* And this one will set all pictures height to 100% */`

Comment: hmmmmm ... height

Comment: hmmm I add style="height: 100%;" and it does not seem to be working, I am learning, sorry

Comment: Can you update your post with more detailed information, like the full code of your template?

Comment: i strongly recommend you learn some basics of html and css before buying a template

Comment: I should know more, you are right ... but I need to learn. I got the roll-overs turned off. Thank you. Trying to figure out how to add my code now

Comment: Download a good code editor [Sublime Text 3 is the best in my opinion](https://www.sublimetext.com/) and start editing your template files there

Comment: Thanks @HenriqueHBR - I got to get these two pieces fixed one way or another... even if I have to pay someone, money up for grabs folks. The rollover thing worked on some of them but not on others.

Comment: You're welcome!, if you need some help with that stuff, i am a experienced web developer/designer, send me a email (henriqueborgeshbr@gmail.com)